# Probability - $a$ white balls, $b$ black balls

Tags: probability

From a urn containing $a$ - white balls and $b$ - black balls are pulled out $k$ balls ($k < a+b$) which are putted aside without knowing their color. Then, it is pulled out another ball. Which is the probability this last ball to be white?

I don't know very much about probability. I would be very happy if you can help me with this exercise and some materials.
thanks:)

Comment: sir second part of the question is little hard for me to understand can you elaborate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy argument is to imagine drawing all $a+b$ balls one at a time and choosing the $(k+1)$-st ball drawn. This is clearly the same as the probability that the first ball drawn is white: just interchange the first and $(k+1)$-st balls in each possible permutation of the $a+b$ balls. And that probability is simply

$$\frac{a}{a+b}\;.$$

Here’s a computational argument, if you prefer that:

Let $w$ be the number of white balls among the $k$ balls that are removed in the first step. Then $p_w$, the probability that the next ball is white, is

$$p_w=\frac{a-w}{a+b-k}\;.$$

There are $\dbinom{a}w\dbinom{b}{k-w}$ ways to draw $w$ white and $k-w$ black balls from the original collection of $a+b$ balls, so the probability of drawing $w$ white balls in the first step is

$$\frac{\dbinom{a}w\dbinom{b}{k-w}}{\dbinom{a+b}k}\;,$$

and the overall probability of drawing a white ball at the second step is

$$p=\sum_{w=0}^k\left(\frac{\dbinom{a}w\dbinom{b}{k-w}}{\dbinom{a+b}k}\cdot\frac{a-w}{a+b-k}\right)\;.$$

Now $$\binom{a}w(a-w)=a\binom{a-1}w$$ and $$\binom{a+b}k(a+b-k)=(a+b)\binom{a+b-1}k\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
p&=\sum_{w=0}^k\frac{a\dbinom{a-1}w\dbinom{b}{k-w}}{(a+b)\dbinom{a+b-1}k}\\\\
&=\frac{a}{a+b}\binom{a+b-1}k^{-1}\sum_{w=0}^k\binom{a-1}w\binom{b}{k-w}\\\\
&=\frac{a}{a+b}\binom{a+b-1}k^{-1}\binom{a+b-1}k\\\\
&=\frac{a}{a+b}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: thanks a lot! can you indicate me some books? some easy materials to familiarize with probabilities? thanks!

Comment: @Iuli: You’re welcome! I added a much simpler argument at the beginning of the answer. I can’t really make any recommendations, because most of what I know about probability I’ve learned in bits and pieces over the years, not from any one or two sources. The calculation actually relies more on what I’ve learned about discrete mathematics rather than probability *per se*.